# Storyboard_Completed event produces Linker Tools Error LNK2019 error

Tags: c++-winrt

Hello fellow programmers,

I tried the xaml autocompletation and the code behind event registration for creating the event handler but got the same error. With buttons and co this works perfectly.

I'm using this function:

```
void STORYBOARD_Completed(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& e);
```

For me this error makes no sense :(

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it :)

I had to include

```
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.h>
```

first.

This was really helpful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#why-is-the-linker-giving-me-a-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error